# how to print stderr message in file using execl() function in c

Tags: c, bash, redirect, stdout, stderr

For example:
command for writing stderr message in file is

```
command > /dev/null 2>text.file"
```

so,

```
execl("gcc" , "gcc" , "-g" , "test.c" , ">" , "/dev/null 2" , ">" , "test" , NULL);
```

execl is returning -1. It is not printing error in text.file

Comment: Redirection is a *shell* feature, and `exec` does not call the shell. Try e.g. `system` instead, it invokes a shell.

Comment: Or manually run your command through the shell by telling exec to run the shell.

Comment: please, explore more @JoachimPileborg

Comment: Take for example `command argument1 argument2 > /dev/null 2>text.file`, the shell only "calls" `command argument1 argument2`, the rest of the command line with the redirection the shell handles internally. The same with pipes, that's a thing that the shell does.

Comment: Also, note that the `exec` family of functions *replace* your current process. So if you want your program to continue working you either have to `fork` a new process or use some other function to call your command.

Answer (score 0):

The stream redirection feature is provided by your shell, and is not a standard way to execute a command.

What you can do is start a shell (like bash), and then you'll be able to redirect stderr from that, by passing your command.

```
execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "gcc -g test.c > /dev/null 2>test", NULL);
```

Comment: Bash expects the first non-option argument to be a shell script that it will execute. Use the `-c` option and pass everything as a single string instead (which is basically what `system` does).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
//Remaining code till here
dup2(open("/dev/null",O_WRONLY), 1); //redirect stdout to /dev/null
dup2(open("text.file",O_WRONLY), 2); //redirect stderr to text.file
execl("gcc" , "gcc" , "-g" , "test.c", NULL);
```

Note: You might need to add O_CREAT flag for text.file.